# Linking to a particular part of deployed notebook?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I'd like to share link that jumps directly to a particular section of deployed notebook, any tips?

Online Mathematica docs provide an anchor to each cell, so you can link to them directly -- [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveValues.html#1390)

I looked through the source of my [deployed notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/forum-ratio-quadratic.nb) and didn't see any anchors, so probably need changes on the notebook side.

In Google docs, it's possible to create such links by first creating Table of Contents (an example [such link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kDAY6A3UXsxwfcnQu9bwDHrK5wZOTalzDzFE8FihVFc/edit#heading=h.eq9lwhm8x6y8))

Comment: I have lectures organized as multiple notebooks (one notebook for one lecture). I used to give in one notebook a reference to a certain equation in another notebook. This reference has been organized as a button that opens this other notebook with the necessary equation being already on the screen. Is it close to what you need? If yes, I will share the code.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch does it work on wolfram cloud? I'm looking for a clickable link to a deployed notebook that I can share online

Comment: I never tried it with the cloud.

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible now, but maybe in the next release. Therefore I deleted my post.

Comment: Maybe you can use cell tags and `NotebookLocate`

Comment: that links takes me to the top of the notebook in latest Chrome....

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov sorry I did not understand, What is "that" referring to in your comment? Do you mean that regardless of the cell you tag, you always return to the top of the notebook? Did you place the tag far down in the notebook ? For me with Firefox, `NotebookLocate` does not place the cursor on the cell, it simply automatically scrolls in such a way that the tagged cell appears at the top of the window. If the tag is on a cell that is already at the top of the window then it would just return to the top of the notebook. But perhaps the behavior is different in chrome.

Comment: Right, I can see NotebookLocate, but I wanted a link that takes me to a specific section, like this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kDAY6A3UXsxwfcnQu9bwDHrK5wZOTalzDzFE8FihVFc/edit#heading=h.eq9lwhm8x6y8) to my Google doc does

Answer (score 2):

### Update

In the recent [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2446627) on the Wolfram Community [Brian Van Vertloo](https://community.wolfram.com/web/brianv) (WRI) showed how it is possible to build HTML from the Documentation pages using `` "PacletTools`" ``:

> The documentation build code that is shipping with the desktop
> products is capable of building HTML pages already, believe it or not.
> The relevant function is PacletDocumentationBuild
> (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PacletTools/ref/PacletDocumentationBuild.html),
> where you use:
>
> ```
> Needs["PacletTools`"];PacletDocumentationBuild[paclet, outdir, "HTML"]
> ```

I haven't tried it, but probably it will add the anchors I described in the original version of this answer.

---

### Original answer

You can easily check that every anchor on a published Documentation page is equal to the `CellID` of the corresponding `Cell` in the offline Documentation:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Your deployed notebook has no `CellID`s set to its `Cell`s.

According to the Docs,

> Typically, a `CellID` will be created automatically by the system for each new cell inserted in a notebook that has the setting `CreateCellID->True`.

> Setting `CreateCellID->True` will not affect `CellID` options of cells already in the notebook at the time the option is set.

Your Notebook has no `CreateCellID->True`. So you should first create a new Notebook and set this option:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CreateCellID -> True]
```

Then you can copy-paste the contents of your original Notebook into the new Notebook. All `Cell`s will have `CellID` assigned. After this you may deploy the new Notebook.

Comment: that sounds like exactly what I need.....how do I get CellID? The example in help for CellId uses `NotebookRead` command but that requires CellTags to be set first

Comment: I think this may need something extra, I just tried deploying notebook with cell ids set, as seen by printing FullForm of the cell, but still no anchors -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/cell-id-test.nb#344570890

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You are right, it seems in deployed version anchors still aren't present. The Documentation pages aren't deployed in this sense, they were exported as HTML pages, I think.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I updated the answer with a possible workaround via building HTML and deploying it to the cloud with [`PacletDocumentationBuild`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PacletTools/ref/PacletDocumentationBuild.html).  See examples on the linked Docs page.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Maybe you can use tags with `Button["interesting tag",NotebookLocate["interesting tag"]]` in text cells or `(* NotebookLocate["interesting tag"] *)` with in-place evaluation (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in input cells. In a cloud notebook, you might have to use `CellPrint` with the `CellTags` option as I did not find a menu item for tags.

#### Usual Mathematica notebook (not the cloud notebook)

In the usual Mathematica notebook (not the cloud notebook) you can add a tag to a cell by right-clicking the cell and adding a tag. For example, you can add a tag called "interesting tag". Then you can use `Button["interesting tag",NotebookLocate["interesting tag"]]` to jump to that tag if the button is in an output cell or text cell.

If you would like to add the "link" in an input cell with an expression that will be evaluated like `s=4+j`, then instead of a button you can use a comment `(* NotebookLocate["interesting tag"]  *)` and use in-place evaluation with Ctrl+Shift+Enter to evaluate only `NotebookLocate["interesting tag"]`. This method has the advantage that you can return back the previous cell using Ctrl+F for search and find and then search for that piece of code. One could also add a tag to the previous cell where the user "teleported from".

#### The cloud notebook

On the cloud notebook, I did not find a menu option for tags but it seems tags still work using `CellPrint` with the `CellTags` option. For example:

> CellPrint[TextCell["abcd", "Text", CellTags -> "tag"]]

then I checked that `NotebookLocate["tag"]` seems to jump to the location of the tag placing the tag at the top of the screen without selecting the tag (unlike in the usual non-cloud notebook). This seems to work for two tags as well so I imagine that this works for any number of tags.